# Difference between SQL JOIN and querying from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

What is the difference between the query

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Persons.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName
```

and this one

```
SELECT Persons.LastName, Persons.FirstName, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons, Orders
WHERE Persons.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Persons.LastName
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause), [What's the difference between the two SQL join notations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251294/whats-the-difference-between-the-two-sql-join-notations), [Is there a difference using join and select from multi-tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592938/is-there-a-difference-using-join-andselect-from-multi-tables), etc.

Comment: Can I assume that in absence of where clause the select returns e a cross join?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a small difference in syntax, but both queries are doing a join on the `P_Id` fields of the respective tables.

In your second example, this is an **implicit** join, which you are constraining in your `WHERE` clause to the `P_Id` fields of both tables.

The join is explicit in your first example and the join clause contains the constraint instead of in an additional `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

They are basically equivalent. In general, the `JOIN` keywords enables you to be more explicit about direction (`LEFT`, `RIGHT`) and type (`INNER`, `OUTER`, `CROSS`) of your join.

Answer (score 3):

[This SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) has a good explanation of the differences in ANSI SQL complaince, and bears similarities to the question asked here.

While (as it has been stated) both queries will produce the same result, I find that it is always a good idea to explicitly state your JOINs.  It's much easier to understand, especially when there are non-JOIN-related evaluations in the WHERE clause.

Explicitly stating your JOIN also prevents you from inadvertently querying a Cartesian product.  In your 2nd query above, if you (for whatever reason) forgot to include your WHERE clause, your query would run without JOIN conditions and return a result set of every row in Persons matched with every row in Orders...probably not something that you want.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in *syntax*, but **not** in the *semantics*.

The explicit `JOIN` syntax:

- is considered more readable and
- allows you to cleanly and **in standard way** specify whether you want `INNER`, `LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER` or a `CROSS` join. This is in contrast to using DBMS-specific syntax, such as old Oracle's `Persons.P_Id = Orders.P_Id(+)` syntax for left outer join, for example.